# Alternative to referrer object

Tags: javascript, html, http

Is there an alternative to referrer object to check where user came from?

history.previous doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is wrong with the referrer? Why can you not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an alternative to referrer object to check where user came from?

No, there isn't.